# How to unit test an Erlang function?

Tags: unit-testing, erlang

```
get_ue_supported_srvcc([]) ->
    ?SRVCC_3GPP_NONE_SUPPORT;
get_ue_supported_srvcc([#sip_contactV{extensionsP = EP} | T]) ->
    case b2bLib:support_tags_to_value(EP) of
    ?SRVCC_3GPP_NONE_SUPPORT ->
        get_ue_supported_srvcc(T);
    Flag ->
        Flag
    end.
```

I  want create a unit test for this function,
Here is my unit test case:

```
get_ue_supported_srvcc_test() ->
    Contact =
    [#sip_contactV{extensionsP =
              [{"+sip.instance",
            {quoted_string,"<urn:gsma:imei:35502406-005233-0>"}},
               {"+g.3gpp.icsi-ref",
            {quoted_string,"urn%3Aurn-7%3A3gpp-service.ims.icsi.mmtel"}},
               "+g.3gpp.mid-call",
               "+g.3gpp.srvcc-alerting",
               "+g.3gpp.ps2cs-srvcc-orig-pre-alerting",
               "video"]}],

    ?assertEqual(7, b2bAtcfLib:get_ue_supported_srvcc(Contact)).
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

```
======================== EUnit ========================
module 'b2bAtcfLib'
  b2bAtcfLib_tests: get_ue_supported_srvcc_test (module 'b2bAtcfLib_tests')...*failed*
in function b2bLib:support_tags_to_value/1
  called as support_tags_to_value([{"+sip.instance",{quoted_string,"<urn:gsma:imei:35502406-005233-0>"}},
 {"+g.3gpp.icsi-ref",
  {quoted_string,"urn%3Aurn-7%3A3gpp-service.ims.icsi.mmtel"}},
 "+g.3gpp.mid-call","+g.3gpp.srvcc-alerting",
 "+g.3gpp.ps2cs-srvcc-orig-pre-alerting","video"])
in call from b2bAtcfLib:get_ue_supported_srvcc/1 (src/b2bAtcfLib.erl, line 1735)
in call from b2bAtcfLib_tests:'-get_ue_supported_srvcc_test/0-fun-0-'/1 (test/unit/b2bAtcfLib_tests.erl, line 49)
in call from b2bAtcfLib_tests:get_ue_supported_srvcc_test/0
**error:undef
  output:<<"">>

  [done in 0.008 s]
=======================================================
```

The error means `b2bLib:support_tags_to_value/1` is `undef`.

The define for this function `b2bLib:support_tags_to_value`:

```
support_tags_to_value(FieldStr) ->
    lists:sum([Val || {Tag, Val} <- ?TAGLIST, lists:member(Tag, FieldStr)]).
```

Comment: Can you provide the output for   support_tags_to_value([{"+sip.instance",{quoted_string,"<urn:gsma:imei:35502406-005233-0>"}},
 {"+g.3gpp.icsi-ref",
  {quoted_string,"urn%3Aurn-7%3A3gpp-service.ims.icsi.mmtel"}},
 "+g.3gpp.mid-call","+g.3gpp.srvcc-alerting",
 "+g.3gpp.ps2cs-srvcc-orig-pre-alerting","video"]).

Answer (score 3):

The error is:

```
**error:undef
```

That means that the test is calling a function that's not defined.  Either the module couldn't be found, or the module in question doesn't define a function with that name and arity.

The whole error message is a bit confusing.  Now that we know that we got a "function undefined" error, we should be looking at this line:

```
in function b2bLib:support_tags_to_value/1
```

Even though it says that the error occurred "in" this function, **this is the function that's undefined.**

So either the test is run in such a way that it doesn't find the `b2bLib` module, or that module doesn't define a function called `support_tags_to_value` taking one argument.  If it's the former, add `-pa path/to/ebin` to the Erlang command line in order to add the right directory to the code path.